# How to change the question number from just '1' to 'Question No. 1.' in the exam class?

Tags: formatting, numbering, exam

I needed to type something like this:

[image]

But wanted to change the 'numbering' to 'Question No. x.' from just 'x.' How should I go about doing that?

An alternative solution is also welcome if what I'm asking for just isn't possible in the exam class. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefine `\questionlabel`. See section 4.9 of the manual for details.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{Question No.~\thequestion.}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question When in doubt, should one provide a minimal working example?
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Innocently asking for a MWE? :-)

Comment: If i want to encircle some special question.. How i can go with??@lockstep

Comment: @David Sorry, but I don't know.