# Alphabet question label

Tags: exam

I'm using the `exam` documentclass, and I'm wondering if there is a way to label the questions with a, b, c, ... instead of with 1, 2, 3, ...

What I have often found is that we could redefine `\questionlabel`, but that still involves a counter (natural number). Example taken from [How to change the question number from just '1' to 'Question No. 1.' in the exam class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82621/how-to-change-the-question-number-from-just-1-to-question-no-1-in-the-exam)

```
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{Question No.~\thequestion.}
```

Maybe there is a way to convert the number from `\thequestion` to a letter from the alphabet?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\alph{question}.}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the OP provided no MWE, I borrowed one from here: [Numbered copies with exam class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272047/numbered-copies-with-exam-class).

The OP was on the right track, in that `\questionlabel` is the macro to be redefined.  In this case, `\alph{<counter>}` is the way a counter is portrayed in lower-case alphabetic format.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\alph{question}.}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question[10]
    Why is there air?

    \question[15]
    How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck
    wood?

    \question[10]
    Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.
  \end{questions}

  \gradetable[v][questions]
\end{document}
```

[image]